# Remove Beaglebone Black services permanently

Tags: debian, beagleboneblack

How do I permanently remove cloud9, bonescript, gateone, etc., from the BeagleBone Black Debian (wheezy) distribution?  I can disable them with these commands:

```
systemctl disable cloud9.service
systemctl disable gateone.service
systemctl disable bonescript.service
systemctl disable bonescript.socket
systemctl disable bonescript-autorun.service
systemctl disable avahi-daemon.service
systemctl disable gdm.service
systemctl disable mpd.service
```

And the disabling survives a reboot, but sometimes when I install a package, some systemd trigger will re-enable them.  How can I permanently remove them?

Comment: Just uninstall the package providing the service, e.g. `apt-get remove mpd`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://kacangbawang.com/beagleboneblack-revc-debloat-part-1/

Answer (score 1):

As the Cloud9 IDE is built on node (which I did not need) I got rid av the whole shebang using:

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Just curious why the negative vote on this answer? Becuase, it seems like this would work just fine IMO.

Comment: Worked for me. Freed up so much space.

Comment: This worked for me on Buster.  First try didn't work completely. Complained of unmet dependencies.  Had to apt-get remove core-c9, then it ran to completion.

Answer (score 0):

systemctl **enable** create a symlink to location /usr/lib/systemd/system and the **disable** will remove the symlink. This two command only affect the auto start behavior of the service on boot time.

So in real time, the service is still there but not auto started if some other service require this service it will get started on request.

To disable the service use **mask** option

```
systemctl mask cloud9.service
systemctl mask gateone.service
systemctl mask bonescript.service
systemctl mask bonescript.socket
systemctl mask bonescript-autorun.service
systemctl mask avahi-daemon.service
systemctl mask gdm.service
systemctl mask mpd.service
```

Answer (score -2):

Try it:

in your terminal, type

```
ls /lib/systemd/system
```

if your service files are there, just delete them.

Comment: Manually deleting files installed by the packaging system is a bad idea. The files will be re-added when the package is updated.

Comment: Sorry because I didn't know those are from the package. I have added some .service manually to that folder to some jobs and I have removed fine