# Debian Stretch: unable to uninstall bonescript

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg, debian-stretch

I am trying to uninstall `bonescript` on Debian 9.5. I run the following command `sudo apt purge bonescript`.

It fails to work, and prints out this statement:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 c9-core-installer : PreDepends: bonescript but it is not going to be installed

E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

**Do you know what I can do to uninstall bonescript?**

I read this article: [Remove Beaglebone Black services permanently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643097/remove-beaglebone-black-services-permanently)
and ran the `systemctl disable` commands it mentions.  I then use `service --status-all` to verify that the bonescript service is no longer running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this issue!

You can fix this by sudo apt-get purge c9-core-installer

Then try to uninstall bonescript

Then you might want to remove nodeJS too!

Comment: Thank you @OliverGee for circling back, lol.  However I ran into this so long ago that I no longer can really check if this is the right solution.  I believe you though :)